# Find the count for last year same week in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below query to find the count from a table based on a date for the last 5-6 weeks as below

```
BEGIN
    SET datefirst 1;
    DECLARE @BeginDate datetime= '2016-10-10' 
    SELECT 
        count(*) as Total
      , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate
    FROM TABLESES
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate) 
        AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate)
    GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DateCreated)
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104)
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104)
    ORDER BY datepart(wk, DateCreated)
END
```

This will return a result set like  below:

```
    Total   WeekNumber  WeekStartDate   WeekEndDate
    51295   36          29.08.2016      04.09.2016
    48133   37          05.09.2016      11.09.2016
    38991   38          12.09.2016      18.09.2016
    38074   39          19.09.2016      25.09.2016
    37192   40          26.09.2016      02.10.2016
    20835   41          03.10.2016      09.10.2016
    23781   42          10.10.2016      16.10.2016
```

Now I want to add one more column in the end with count for the same week number in last year.

Can I achieve the same in this query itself? Or should I write a totally different query for it? And how can I make this query?

Comment: Cant you just count the last year and join on weeknumber? So create 2 CTEs, one with 2016 data, one with 2015 data and then join those on weeknumber, then you get the total from both years on same row.

Comment: The most difficult part is to figure out the exact range of dates in the previous year that corresponds to same week numbers. 10/10/2016 is Monday - first day of the week. 10/10/2015 is Saturday, so simple `DATEADD(year, -1, ...)` is not enough. I would strongly recommend to use a Calendar table.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov dates can be ignored.. Week number only is relevant in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` with `DATEDIFF` to get the same thing for the previous year:

```
SELECT 
        count(*) as Total
      , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate
    FROM TABLESES
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate) 
        AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate)
    GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DateCreated)
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104)
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
        count(*) as Total
      , datepart(wk, DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated )) as WeekNumber
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate
    FROM TABLESES
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate) 
        AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate)
    GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))/7,0),104)
      , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))/7,6),104)
    ORDER BY datepart(wk, DATEDIFF(year,1,DateCreated ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your end-result to a temp table and then do something like this:

Be sure to check your date logic with previous year. But hope you get the logic. I havent tested if your "Version" is correct as i have wroted, but i hope you get the picture.

**Result with test version**

[image]

**TEST Version:**

```
DECLARE @Weeks1 TABLE(
Total int,
Weeknumber INT,
WeekStartDate nvarchar(50),
WeekEndDate nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @Weeks2 TABLE(
Total int,
Weeknumber INT,
WeekStartDate nvarchar(50),
WeekEndDate nvarchar(50) 
)


insert into @Weeks1 (Total,Weeknumber,WeekStartDate,Weekenddate)

values  ('51295', '36'        ,'29.08.2016'     ,'04.09.2016'),
    ('48133', '37'        ,'05.09.2016'     ,'11.09.2016'),
    ('38991', '38'        ,'12.09.2016'     ,'18.09.2016'),
    ('38074', '39'        ,'19.09.2016'     ,'25.09.2016'),
    ('37192', '40'        ,'26.09.2016'     ,'02.10.2016'),
    ('20835', '41'        ,'03.10.2016'     ,'09.10.2016'),
    ('23781', '42'        ,'10.10.2016'     ,'16.10.2016')


   insert into @Weeks2 (Total,Weeknumber,WeekStartDate,Weekenddate)

  values  ('324234', '36'       ,'29.08.2015'     ,'04.09.2015'),
    ('22333', '37'        ,'05.09.2015'     ,'11.09.2015'),
    ('23444', '38'        ,'12.09.2015'     ,'18.09.2015'),
    ('566666', '39'       ,'19.09.2015'     ,'25.09.2015'),
    ('4345', '40'         ,'26.09.2015'     ,'02.10.2015'),
    ('8657', '41'         ,'03.10.2015'     ,'09.10.2015'),
    ('8567567', '42'      ,'10.10.2015'     ,'16.10.2015')


Select a.Total,b.Total as 
LastYearTotal,a.Weeknumber,A.WeekStartDate,a.Weekenddate from @Weeks1 a 
inner join @Weeks2 b on a.Weeknumber = b.Weeknumber
```

**With your version:**

```
DECLARE @Weeks1 TABLE(
Total int,
Weeknumber INT,
WeekStartDate nvarchar(50),
WeekEndDate nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @Weeks2 TABLE(
Total int,
Weeknumber INT,
WeekStartDate nvarchar(50),
WeekEndDate nvarchar(50)
)


BEGIN
SET datefirst 1;
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime= '2016-10-10' 

insert into @Weeks1 (Total,Weeknumber,WeekStartDate,Weekenddate)

SELECT 
    count(*) as Total
  , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate
FROM TABLESES
WHERE   
    CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate) 
    AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate)
GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DateCreated)
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104)
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104)
ORDER BY datepart(wk, DateCreated)
END



BEGIN
SET datefirst 1;
DECLARE @BeginDate2 datetime= '2015-10-10' 

insert into @Weeks2 (Total,Weeknumber,WeekStartDate,Weekenddate)

SELECT 
    count(*) as Total
  , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate
FROM TABLESES
WHERE   
    CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate2) 
    AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate2)
GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DateCreated)
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104)
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104)
ORDER BY datepart(wk, DateCreated)
END


Select a.Total,b.Total as 
LastYearTotal,a.Weeknumber,A.WeekStartDate,a.Weekenddate from @Weeks1 a 
inner join @Weeks2 b on a.Weeknumber = b.Weeknumber
```

Comment: Just changed the second begindate variable to begindate2 since u cannot have 2 variables with same name. Else i think it would work.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. is the message ia m getting

Comment: Perhaps because we do not use same dates. Correct the dates to how you normally write it. And make sure the datatype on the table is correct. Or make the Date columns to nvarchar instead of datatype DATE

Comment: I could imagine that your WeekStartDate and WeekEndDate is nvarchar or varchar, since you have 29.08.2016 - I dont think it would  work in datatype date. So try to make the table string based on columns instead.

Comment: I changes the type to nvarchar and the result is 

 String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: You need to change it on both tables, it works fine for me. Let me update my table.

Comment: Yes its working fine I am checking the results for 1 or 2 weeks manually to make sure count is correct

Answer (score 1):

If only weeks matter you can make some date calculations first and have a simpler query

```
SET datefirst 1;

 DECLARE @BeginDate datetime = '2016-10-10'; -- must be start of the week , <= last week -6
 declare @nweeks int = 6;
 -- this year interval
 declare @b1Date datetime = dateadd(week, -@nweeks , @BeginDate); --inclusive
 declare @e1Date datetime = dateadd(week, 1 , @BeginDate); -- exclusive
 declare @thisYear int = datepart(year, @b1Date);
 -- previous year interval
 declare @bwk int = datepart(week, @b1Date);
 declare @year2 datetime= dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@b1Date)-1,0);
 declare @b2Date datetime = dateadd(week, @bwk-1, @year2);
 declare @e2Date datetime = dateadd(week, @bwk + @nweeks, @year2);
 -- check it
 select @BeginDate, @b1Date, @e1Date, @bwk,  @b2Date, @e2Date, datepart(week, @b2Date);

SELECT 
    count(case datepart(year, DateCreated) when @thisYear then 1 end) as TotalThisYear
  , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datepart(week,DateCreated)-@bwk -1,@b1Date),104) as WeekStartDate
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(day,7*(datepart(week,DateCreated)-@bwk-1)+6,@b1Date),104) as WeekEndDate
  , count(case datepart(year, DateCreated) when @thisYear-1 then 1 end) as TotalPrev
FROM TABLESES
WHERE   
    CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= @b1Date AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <@e1Date
    OR
    CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= @b2Date AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <@e2Date    
GROUP BY datepart(wk, DateCreated)
ORDER BY datepart(wk, DateCreated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your same query but with few modifications.  I have used 2 CTE's , one for your query and another for prior year weeks. Then join both on the weeknumber to fetch the needed last column as you can see below.

```
BEGIN  
SET datefirst 1;  
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime= '2016-10-10'  

;WITH CTE1 as
  SELECT 
    count(*) as Total  
  , datepart(wk, DateCreated) as WeekNumber  
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104) as WeekStartDate  
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104) as WeekEndDate  
FROM TABLESES  
WHERE     
    CONVERT(date,DateCreated) >= DATEADD(DAY, -42, @BeginDate)   
    AND CONVERT(date,DateCreated) <= DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginDate)  
GROUP BY      datepart(wk, DateCreated)  
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,0),104)  
  , convert(VARCHAR(20),dateadd(week,datediff(day,0,DateCreated )/7,6),104)    

,CTE2 as  
SELECT count(*) as Total    
    ,datepart(wk, dateadd(year, -1, DateCreated)) as WeekNumber  
 FROM TABLESES    
GROUP BY datepart(wk, dateadd(year, -1, DateCreated))  

SELECT CTE1.*, CTE2.Total  
FROM CTE1 JOIN CTE2  
ON CTE1.WeekNumber  = CTE2.WeekNumber  

  END
```